# Is it possible to profile memory only by storing allocated pointer address in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator, memory-profiling

I want to create a simple memory profiler. It will store the address returned by operator `new` (or directly from `malloc()`) associated with allocated size - as an event in some database. Then I want to track the deallocation using only the address passed to operator `delete` (or `free()`).

Is it true, that in C++ I can be sure that pointer passed to the operator `delete` (or `free()`) always will be the one previously allocated?

I'm in doubt if there is some hidden pointer arithmetic inside C++ allocator, that allows to delete upcasted or downcasted pointers instead of original ones.

Comment: No you can't be sure. There might be bugs in the code that causes it to pass invalid pointers to `delete` or `free`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true, that in C++ I can be sure that pointer passed to the operator delete (or free()) always will be the one previously allocated?

Yes, this is true. It could also be a null pointer, in which case your function should do nothing.

> [The behavior of the standard library implementation of this function is undefined unless ptr is a null pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard library implementation of `operator new`...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

Since most code is written for the standard library implementation of `operator new`/`delete`, it does not pass other pointers to `operator delete`.

It is possible for someone to write a class with an overloaded `operator new` and `operator delete` which do not have this requirement. In that case, it won't call your custom allocator, either.

Comment: Although you may want the profiler to fail gracefully in the case where the program under test has undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

> I'm in doubt if there is some hidden pointer arithmetic inside C++ allocator, that allows to delete upcasted or downcasted pointers instead of original ones.

The allocated/deallocated memory is still the same, the difference is which destructor is called *before* the deallocation.

At the debug level you have the same pointer. A simple memory profiler can be implemented by overloading operator new/delete. You can have a map that stores pointers and check also if something not previously stored with your new operator is passed to delete.

Also, there are memory allocations outside the C++ level you might want to profile. In Windows, VirtualAlloc, COM memory, handles, etc.